# NSPopover tooltip color change

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Im totally new to drawing in cocoa and the graphics related stuff.
I'm making a popover from the `StatusItem` button when clicked. But anyways the default appearance of the `NSPopover` is transient in OS X, but what I want is solid black background. So far I managed to do this. Heres my PopOver view Controller, the View object is totally empty yet.

```
class PopOverController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var PopView: PopOver!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.PopView.wantsLayer=true;
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
         PopView.layer?.backgroundColor=NSColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    }

}
```

But anyways this code when compiled fills the Popover with the black solid color except that the little triangle's color from which the popover comes out is unchanged. So How can I not only set the content of the popover but also that **popping tooltip?**